# Invoke multiple loggers pattern in a service class

Tags: c#, logging, design-patterns, log4net

We use in our projects classes log4net, and below you will see the pattern used everywhere when we need to log something, so I've decided to abstract it in my own interface/implementation to get rid of the log4net dependency everywhere.

```
private readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

In some cases though, we have more than one logger used inside the class.

```
private readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
private readonly ILog _backupLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("BackupLogger");
```

In this case code like the below is valid.

```
private void LogError<T>(string msg, string serverError, string debugInfo, T data) where T : class
{
     _log.Error($"{msg} saving entry using log4net instead which must be handled manually. server error: {serverError}. api debug: {debugInfo}");
     _backupLogger.Error(data.ToJson());
}
```

Trying to think of a pattern where in a service class I can add additional loggers, maybe via `AddLogger(string loggerName)` method and then invoke all available loggers when `Error` method is invoked, could "Chain of responsibility" or "Decorator" apply here, can't seem to recognize it.

Comment: Why multiple loggers? normally the logs are configured in such a way that, based on a keyword or level or something like that the actual message is stored in different places, like errors to db an info to txt file for example. Why are you (seemingly) making things complicated? What's the purpose.

Comment: Thinking about your argument it does make sense, I should think of it and redesign accordingly. It's just that log4net enforces having different log configurations and this is how it was setup, I believe that you are correct.